# Bundler's :require option in a gemfile?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, bundler, radix

How would one go about using Bundler's `:require=>` in a gemspec? For instance, I would like to only use sinatra/base as a runtime dependency. This works in a gemfile:

```
gem 'sinatra', :require => 'sinatra/base'
```

but does not work in the gemspec (even when bundler is required in the gemspec):

```
s.add_runtime_dependency 'sintatra', :require => 'sinatra/base'
```

The error is "Illformed requirement [{:require=>"sinatra/base"}]"

Anybody else find themselves in a similar situation?

Answer (score 0):

In the gemspec file you can specify the gem's dependencies only. This file doesn't do require for you. You should require dependencies in the ruby code.

On the other hand you can create a Gemfile to help you in the development environment. But the Gemfile is not loaded when you are using the gem on other projects.

Comment: Right, though I want to make sinatra/base a dependency which will load when other projects require my gem (as opposed to sinatra in its entirety).

Comment: You cannot do this. Dependencies should be gems. sinatra/base is just a file.